# How to check if a dynamically created element already exists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I create an element dynamically:

```
var $el = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
```

I want to append the element (`$el`) somewhere, but it shouldn't have an `id`.

How do I know if it has been appended before or not?

**edit**
I thought this should work

```
if($($el, "#target").length == 0)
    $("#target").append($el);
```

but that was wrong

Comment: You can write that like this too: `var $el = $("<div>").addClass("someclass");`

Comment: @micha or as `var $el = $('<div>', { 'class': 'someClass'} );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply check to see if it has a parent:

```
var $el = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
//Code you wrote that may or may not attach it to the DOM

if($el.parent().length === 0) {
    //The element has not been added to the DOM because it doesn't not have a parentNode
}
```

However, if you have no idea what is actually being done with the element, you may have other problems with your code.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, and you need to check if another `<div class='someclass'>` already exists before appending `$el`, you can do:

```
if ($("div.someclass").length === 0) {
  // it has not been created yet, create a new one
  var $el = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
}
```

To check if it is already a child node of some other element, use `.find()`

```
if ($("#parentNode").find("div.someclass").length === 0 {
  // it has not been created yet, create a new one
  var $el = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
}
```

Comment: `.someclass` class may be used for other element, i just want to perform a check about this element with the same class.

Comment: @OmidAmraei You can test the containing element to see if it is already there using `.find("div.someclass")`

Comment: there could be some another elements with `someclass` in container

Comment: @OmidAmraei Then you are going to need a better selector, such as an `id` attribute to find a more specific element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to find whether this *exact* element is already in the DOM, rather than some other arbitrary element that happens to have the same class.

If so, I believe this will work.

First, get the originally created element as an `HTMLElement` object rather than a jQuery object:

```
var el = $el.get(0);
```

then try to [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) it in the doc:

```
var $match = $(document).find(el);
var found = ($match.length > 0);
```

this won't be efficient, though - restrict the selector `document` to a narrower part of your DOM if you can!

Your edit suggests you could use `#target` as that selector.

Comment: @OmidAmraei then please knock out a minimal test case on jsfiddle.net that shows it.

Comment: @OmidAmraei p.s `.find(element)` requires jQuery 1.6 or later

Comment: I user jQuery 1.7 dear Alnitak

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, he is creating the element out of thin air, therefore the exact same element cannot be in the dom.

Comment: @Esailija I was assuming that there was some (omitted) code that _may_ have added `$el` and that he needs to know later whether that is indeed the case.

Comment: @Alnitak then he should add that code as it changes the question completely, but for now this doesn't make sense. I am voting for close anyway :/. Also you can just simply check the `.parentNode` property for not null to see if an element is in the DOM.

Comment: @Esailija I think you're right man, it seems i have to choose an ID for my element

Comment: @Esailija simply should be a lot of `<div class='someclass'>` in the parent node. it make sense, but i think jQuery has no solution for that at least.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want one element, you should really be using an ID with the element, and then checking for it in a similar way to how Michael has above. using

```
var el = $('<div id="someID" class="someClass" />');
```

I'm also not sure why you are using `$el` instead of just `el`

Comment: using `$el` is a convention some programmers use to indicate that the variable is a jQuery object and not a native element.  It reminds them that they needn't write `$($el).method()` and can just write `$el.method()` instead.